# Programming an internet browser that barely connects to the internet

Tags: browser, proxy, connection

Hypothetically speaking, would it be possible to create an internet browser that had almost no actual connection to the internet?
And if so, how would you create it?

Would you proxy the connection to other servers?

Would you create have other websites create a bundle of code that could be downloaded onto client computers, and then they would have no connection after that?

P.S. this is a very generalized question I was just interested in responses from some more knowledgeable people.

Comment: Browsers don't require an internet connection, they do make use of one though.  You can browse local content all day long if you wanted too.

Comment: @dcreight Good point!

Answer (score 0):

All browsers can work without connection to internet.For exemple You can store your website on your computer and use the browser to display.
Or just to use a web application on your company's network.